# Changes not being read from files by Apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

New to php and php-servers so please forgive my ignorance;

**Context**

I am adding a moodle plugin which is written in php, my plugin uses files which allows for client interaction, for example *stuff.js*.

**Problem:**

If I refresh the browser, the changes I made to *stuff.js* are not being fetched/read or whatever. However changes made in files such as *index.php* are read/displayed.

**Failed attempts at a resolution**

**restarting apache**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**reloading apache**

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

**Enabling and installing xdebug**

[The guide used for enabling and installing xdebug](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#installAndConfigureXDebug)

**Browser attempts**

- Disabling cache
- ctrl + f5
- ctrl + shift + f5
- closing/reopening browser/tab
- opened dev tools and empty cache and hard reload
  **Meta data**:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04, PHP version: PHP5, moodle version: 2.9.2, Apache version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: yea, I guess i should update, i opened dev tools and empty cache and hard reload